# Django: How to make a form with foreignkey

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hi I am working with Django and I am trying to make a little system to register people and teams.

So far I can create teams and people in the admin site.

Now, I want to make a public form, where i.e. a trainer can register his team.

The **Team** has a foreignkey to **Bundesland** (the state).

I want a dropdown list that shows the states, I already made in the admin site. And then chose from it in the form. My "python crash course"-book doesn't cover this, so please help me. The answers I found so far in the documentation and on stackoverflow didn't work for me.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Bundesland(models.Model):
    bdl_kurz = models.CharField(max_length=2)  #abbreviation
    bdl_lang = models.CharField(max_length=25) #full name
    --snip--

class Team(models.Model):
    bdl = models.ForeignKey(Bundesland)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    plz = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    ort = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    strasse = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    strnr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    --snip--
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

from .models import Team

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        bdl = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='bdl_lang.objects.all()), empty_label=None)
        fields = ['name', 'plz', 'ort', 'strasse', 'strnr', 'telefon', 'email']
        labels = {'plz': 'PLZ', 'ort': 'Ort', 'strasse': 'Straße', 'strnr': 'Hausnr.', 'telefon': 'Telefon', 'email': 'Email'}
```

**new_team.html:**

```
<p>New Team</p>
<form action="{% url 'teilnehmer:new_team' %}" method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
 <button name="submit">Submit data</button>
</form>
```

**views.py:** (if important)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Bundesland, Gewichtsklasse, Team, Kaempfer
from .forms import TeamForm

--snip--

def new_team(request):
    """Add a new team."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form
        form = TeamForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teilnehmer:index'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'teilnehmer/new_team.html', context)
```

Comment: Defining a field in Meta isn't allowed, it should be at the class level. But why don't you just include `bdl` in the `fields` list?

Comment: For real? Man, I didnt think it is that easy and it works as wanted. Sorry for trashing this site. And big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I can pick out a number of problems in your code.

1. `bdl = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='bdl_lang.objects.all()), empty_label=None)` - you do not need the starting quote right after the equal sign.
2. `bdl_lang` is a `CharField` so `bdl_lang.objects.all()` doesn't make sense. The queryset is an order dict of Django objects (defined via  a model class). Replace this with `bdl.objects.all()`. From here, insert a `__unicode__(self)` method in your class `Bundesland`. This method should return the name you want in your choices. From looking at your code, it seems like you would want to return `bdl_lang`.
3. You need to include `bdl` in your fields option.

I hope this helps!